# Domain aware React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, hostname

I have an application which uses React Router and serves content based upon the following paths. In this example, Sally and Sunny have their own pages at the urls below,

- www.myapp.com/sally
- www.myapp.com/sunny

Now what I would like to do is to match each of these when the request is coming from another host like the following,

- sally.herapp.com <-- match and serve same content found at www.myapp.com/sally
- sunny.hisapp.com <-- match and serve same content found at www.myapp.com/sunny

What I would like is to use the same app and have it match and server the routes /sally and /sunny on different subdomains and domains. To be clear, I have DNS CNAME entries for sally and sunny at herapp.com hisapp.com respectively.

Is this possible with React Router? Thank you!

Comment: Not possible with react router. React router is just a javascript framework. It cannot create subdomains. You could create subdomains using DNS A records and have them redirect to the associated page

Comment: Thanks @CharlieMartin to clarify, I don't want to create subdomains. I set up CNAME records. I want my app to be "subdomain aware".

When accessed from 
www.myapp.com/sally it will match the route /sally

When accessed from
sally.herapp.com it will also match the route /sally

Comment: Okay I updated the question to clarify further—also the formatting was off and it looks better now =)

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with React Router. React Router uses the history API to push new url states without triggering a page refresh. It does this by calling [`window.history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), which will throw an error if you pass a different origin (a subdomain). From the `pushState` docs...

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception.

Subdomains are treated as separate origins by the browser with separate [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) restrictions for security purposes, since they usually point to different machines.

The best you can do is use some server side code (e.g. an nginx config) to reverse proxy the request from `sally.herapp.com` to `myapp.com/sally`. This would serve the page at `sally.herapp.com`, but it would still require a round trip to the server.

You might as well have a separate JS bundle with it's own instance of react router for each subdomain, since react router cannot link across subdomains without a round trip to the server, so you've lost the benefits of a single page application anyway

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure I understand here, let me clarify.... There are different requests coming from different domains to the same running application and it works fine just that I want to route matching to be dynamic depending upon the origin of the request. 

Currently the following serves up the same content,

 - myapp.com/sally
 - sally.myapp.com/sally 

Whereas I want to match and serve up the same content visible at `myapp.com/sally` at `sally.myapp.com`. 

You maintain that it is not possible to inspect the origin and switch accordingly?

Comment: I see. You might be able to write a custom `Route` component that matches based on the domain. So the route with path `/`, checks the domain and serves the component for `/sally` when domain is `sally.myapp.com`. But you'll also need to dynamically change the `basepath` or write a custom `Link` component so that your links are correct (`/sally/xxx/yyy` vs `/xxx/yyy`)

Comment: @swidnikk hey were you able to do what you were looking for?